# Regular expression for new Date object in JSON

Tags: java, regex, json, date, format

I'm stuck on this particular regular expression. I have the following:

```
"sampleDay": newDate(1402027200000)
```

and need it to display in the following format: `1402027200000`

So far, I am able to entirely strip the date with the following in Java:

```
myDate = myDateJSON.replaceAll("newDate\\([^\\)]*\\)" ,"\" \"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use capturing groups also,

```
String str = "\"sampleDay\": newDate(1402027200000)";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*?newDate\\(([^\\)]*)\\).*", "$1")); // 1402027200000
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only digits then replace all non-digits using `\D`

```
String str = "\"sampleDay\": newDate(1402027200000)";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));  // print 1402027200000
```

OR use [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to negate any digits using `[^\d]`

```
String str = "\"sampleDay\": newDate(1402027200000)";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""));
```

Read more about [Java Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the JSON date to a Java date using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), deal with conversion issues, and re-format it back to a string (again with SimpleDateFormat)

```
String jsonDate = "1402027200000";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDDHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
  Date date = sdf.parse(jsonDate);
} catch(ParseException e) {
  System.out.printf("%s is not parsable!%n", jsonDate);
  throw e; // Rethrow the exception.
}
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

In Java8 you can use  [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html):

```
String jsonDate = "1402027200000";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMDDHHmmss");
try {
  LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(jsonDate, dtf);

} catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
  //Exception handling
  System.out.printf("%s is not parsable!%n", jsonDate);
  throw e; // Rethrow the exception.
}
String formattedDate = dtf.format(date);
```